# Invalid prop `function` of type `boolean`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint

I am trying to pass a function from one of my JavaScript files to a component.

```
<Button onPress={() => console.log(title)} />
```

I have tried to assign the function to a variable. I have tried to place the function inside the components files. Regardless of what I do, I receive the same error:

> Invalid prop `onPress` of type `boolean` supplied to
>   `TouchableOpacity`, expected `function`.

Here is my code for the Button component.

```
const Button = ({ onPress }) => {
const { buttonStyle,
buttonTextStyle } = styles;

return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress{...onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
        <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>Click Me!!</Text>  
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

};

Each time I do not put the `...` in the onPress function, I receive this error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected `...`

I am new to React Native and have been debugging for a good hour now. Stumped on what I am doing wrong. I do not understand why the code believes the function is a Boolean type. For reference, I am using ESLint and the extension [rally coding](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/eslint-config-rallycoding).

Comment: you are missing assignment. `onPress = {onPress} `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onPress` accepts a function which you are passing down in the props. Just reference the destructured property. Also you are missing an `=` in the `onPress` attribute.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help, please mark the question as answered if it did resolve your issue, thanks